# When applying for an Indian Passport, how do I know if I'm in the ECR or non-ECR category?

Tags: visas, passports, indian-citizens, terminology, ecr

I'm applying for a fresh Passport from India but I don't know what "ECR" & "NON-ECR" mean:

> "Is applicant eligible for Non-ECR category?"
>
> [Yes] [No]

I've already Graduated from University. I don't know whether to choose "YES" or "NO"?. I'm Indian by birth.

Comment: Here you have stated that children up to 18 years of age. AS it means as they are under 18 years or minor they are eligibel for non ecr category.

Answer (score 12):

I am an Indian, with a Masters Degree and in my Passport its marked as ECNR (Emigration Clearance Not Required).

Being said that, as per [Path2USA](http://www.path2usa.com/ecnr-emigration-clearance-not-required)

> **Eligibility for ECNR:**
>
> The following applicants are eligible for ECNR status regardless of
> its requirement in certain countries -
>
> 1. Holders of Diplomatic / Official Passports
> 2. Gazetted Government servants, their spouses and dependent children
> 3. Income tax payers, their spouses and dependent children
> 4. Professional degree holders
> 5. **Persons having educational qualification of matriculation and above.**
> 6. Seamen who are in possession of Continuous Discharge Certificate
>    (CDC), or Sea Cadets and Deck Cadets
> 7. Persons holding permanent immigration Visas, such as the visas of UK, USA and Australia.
> 8. Persons possessing two or three years’ diploma from any institute
>    recognized by the National Council for Vocational Training (NCVT) or
>    State Council of Vocational Training (SCVT).
> 9. Qualified Nurses, recognized under the Indian Nursing Council Act,
>    1947.
> 10. Persons above the age of 50 years.
> 11. All persons who have been staying abroad for more than three years
>     (the period of three years could be either in one stretch or
>     broken) and their spouses.
> 12. Children up to 18 years of age.

So, your answer will be **YES**

Comment: The various categories of people who are considered Non-ECR and the documents they can produce is given in the [official page](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/onlineHtml/NonEcrDocuments.html)

Comment: Do you need to be married for the 11th criteria? It says "and spouses" but if I'm single and I stayed abroad for more than three years, do I qualify?

Comment: "And spouses" means that if you qualify under this criteria on your own, then your spouse also qualifies, no matter whether he or she meets those conditions. So being single is no problem.

Answer (score 7):

Google brought this up immediately and Wikipedia has a section on it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_passport#New_additional_security_features).

They call it "ECR (Emigration Check Required) or ECNR (Emigration Check Not Required)."

The category for an ECNR that appears to apply for you is "holder of a matriculation certificate."