# Am I eligible for non-ECR category passport?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, ecr

I am a citizen of India and am applying for a passport. I am confused about the right category, Emigration Check Required (ECR) or whether I am eligible for the non-ECR category. I passed diploma & my current age is 34.

Comment: Hi pravin. Your question doesn't give enough information. What are you trying to do, what is your current state, what is the question you want answered, and what does ECR mean?

Comment: @DJClayworth: [tag:ecr]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When applying for an Indian Passport, how do I know if I'm in the ECR or non-ECR category?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38859/when-applying-for-an-indian-passport-how-do-i-know-if-im-in-the-ecr-or-non-ecr)

Comment: I didn't vote that this question was unclear! I voted that it was a duplicate. Thanks SO.

Answer (score 1):

The Indian Government's Passport Division lists those [eligible for non-ECR passports](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/onlineHtml/NonEcrDocuments.html); and view the linked page to see the documents required for each:

> - All holders of Diplomatic/official Passports: No separate document is required except Diplomatic passport.
> - All GAZETTED Government servants, their spouses and dependent children.
> - All persons having educational qualifications of matriculation and above
> - All persons above the age of 50 years
> - All children up to the age of 18 years. (For re-issue of passport, after they attain the age of 18 years, documents to prove their non-ECR category has to be submitted, else ECR stamping will be done)
> - Income-Tax payers (including Agricultural Income-Tax payees) in their individual capacity, their spouses and dependent children below the age 18 years
> - Persons possessing two years diploma from any institute recognized by the National Council for Vocational Training (NCVT) or State Council of Vocational Training (SCVT), or persons holding three years diploma/equivalent degree from institutions, such as Polytechnics recognized by the Central/State Governments of India
> - Nurses possessing qualifications recognized under the Indian Nursing Council Act. 1947
> - All professional Degree holders , their spouses and dependent children. Examples of professional degree holders are Doctors holding MBBS degree or equivalent degree in AYURVED or HOMEOPATHY, accredited Journalists, Engineers, Chartered Accountants, Cost Accountants, Lecturers, Teachers, Scientists, Advocates, etc
> - All persons who have been staying abroad for more than three years (the period of three years could be either in one stretch or broken) and their spouses
> - Seamen who are in possession of Continuous Discharge Certificate (CDC), or Sea Cadets and Deck Cadets
> - Persons holding Permanent Immigration Visa, such as the visas of UK, USA and Australia.
>
> Note: If the applicant does not have Non-ECR status then All such ECR passport holders need to obtain Emigration Clearance Certificate from the Protector-General of Emigrants, Ministry of Overseas India Affairs.